# Has anyone successfully exported content from the Paragraphs Modules via UUID Features?

Tags: features

I know this functionality isn't supported by default. I found the following patches and applied them, but still not luck.

- [Add UUID module support](https://www.drupal.org/node/2471174#comment-9996447)
- [Add Paragraphs module support](https://www.drupal.org/node/2471182#comment-9971515)

Is there another way to deploy content from paragraphs across environments? Feeds maybe?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to get this to work??

Comment: I have not unfortunately.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this, same here, no way of doing that...huge problem, I have 850 taxonomy terms and thousands of content items, nearly need to move away from Drupal on this...